# How to create Scrollable and zoomable canvas in android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, scroll, zooming

During the past weeks I was looking for appropriate solution for zooming and  scrolling functionality on a custom view.In my custom view I am drawing bitmaps on my canvas in onDraw() and creating new bitmap and canvas in onSizeChanged().

my code snippet here :

onDraw() method.In this method I am calling drawBitmap() this method takes image times from pagesProvider class that is my custom class.

```
Bitmap backBitmap = pagesProvider.getPageBitmap(tile);
src = new Rect();
dst = new Rect(); 
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        drawBitmap(canvas, b, src, dst);
    }
```

Here it is drawBitmap() this method drawBitmap on canvas based on Color mode. This color takes from my custom Options Class.And again I am drawing bitmap on canvas with mBitmap this mBitmap created on onSizeChanged() and drawing path on canvas.

```
private void drawBitmap(Canvas canvas, Bitmap backBitmap, Rect src, Rect dst) {

    if (colorMode != Options.COLOR_MODE_NORMAL) {

        paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(
                Options.getColorModeMatrix(this.colorMode))));
        canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, src, dst, paint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, null);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mTopBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint); // mTopBitmap canvas is creating new bitmap on backBitmap bitmap canvas.
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

}
```

onSizeChanged() :

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;

    mTopBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mTopBitmap);

}
```

If I remove canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); line from drawBitmap() canvas is not drawing paths on mTopBitmap canvas.And if I remove canvas.drawBitmap(mTopBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint); paths are drawn on backBitmap but those paths resetting when touch up.

In onTouch UP I am calling mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); for drawing new path on mTopBitmap.

And My problem was I want to scroll the mTopBitmap canvas content whatever I draw on mCanvas and zoom the mTopBitmap canvas content of mCanvas.

I written zooming functionality and I added scroller according to backBitmap size.It's working fine.But I have confuse with mTopBitmap canvas how I can put scroll and zoom into mTop Canvas.

Comment: use Canvas.concat(Matrix) or a combination of Canvas.translate / Canvas.scale methods

Comment: I have a library that may do what you need, a zoomable image view with support for extension e.g. drawing and overlays that move and scale with the image. You probably don't want to scrap what you have but it might be useful. Demo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample Code: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: Hi @pskink How those methods are useful when scrolling.I think those methods are useful when zooming.

Comment: use Canvas.translate() for moving the Canvas in any direction, but Canvas.concat is IMHO better than a combination of scale / translate